# How to retrieve Lookup List's lookup values in a third List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I am using sharepoint 2010 Lists.I have 3 Lists RoleFamily,Roles and Employees. RoleFamily defines under which Family a role exists.There fore RoleFamily is the Primary.The below image shows the roleFamily List.
Title                            :  Single line of text Checked
RoleFamilyName                   :  Single line of text
RoleFamilyDescription            :  Single line of text
Created By                       :  Person or Group
Modified By                      :  Person or Group

The Roles List has a lookup to RolesFamily and is shown below. 
Title:  Single line of text Checked
RoleTitle                       :  Single line of text
RoleFamily                      :  Lookup Checked
RoleFamily:ID                   : Lookup
RoleDesc                        : Single line of text
RoleNos                         :  Single line of text Checked
Created By                      :  Person or Group
Modified By                     :  Person or Group

The Employees List is the last.I need to select the Roles, automaticaly I need to get the RoleFamily also in this Employees List as RoleFamily is a lookup to Roles.Each Role is listed under a unique roleFamily.The Employees List is Shown below.

EmployeeFirstName              :Single line of text Item
EmployeeID                     :Single line of text Item
EmployeeLastName               :Single line of text Item
EmployeeName                   :Single line of text Item
EmployeeType                   :Lookup Item
EmployeeType:EmployeeTypeId    :  Lookup Item
LineManager1                   : Person or Group Item
LineManager2                   : Person or Group Item
LineManager3                   : Person or Group Item
ResourceType                   : Lookup Item
ResourceType:ID                : Lookup Item
RoleTitle                      :  Lookup Item
RoleTitle:ID                   : Lookup Item
Title                          :  Single line of text Item
Created By                     :  Person or Group
Modified By                    : Person or Group

When I select Role Title from the New or Edit Form I need to get corresponding RoleFamily of the Role selected in dropdown list in to the Employees List.How can this be done.

please refer below link, as i dont have points to post images here.:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602015/how-to-retrieve-lookup-lists-lookup-values-in-a-third-list

Comment: Hey Image is not visible... Can you put it again....

Comment: Hey @Rahul Gokani, since i dont have enough points to post images here,Please refer stack overflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602015/how-to-retrieve-lookup-lists-lookup-values-in-a-third-list

Comment: please don't post the same question into multiple Stack sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily using custom form. using asp.net and c# coding through ajax features. Newly created aspx page can be bound to Employees List New and Edit forms.

Have a look at the following steps:

1. Create an Empty SharePoint Project, then right click the project,
   add SharePoint “Layouts” Mapped Folder.
2. Right click the project name, add New item Application Page, then
   add the custom code there.
3. Under Features, add a feature, right click the added feature then
   add an event receiver, override the FeatureActivated method to set
   the new edit/new form as the default form.

How to set new form as default form:

```
SPList lstTest = web.Lists["Shared Documents"];

string newUrl = string.Format("layouts/NewEditForm.aspx", web.ServerRelativeUrl, lstTest.RootFolder.Url);

var form = web.GetFile(newUrl);

if (form != null && form.Exists)

{

 //string newFomrUrl = lstTest.DefaultEditFormUrl.Replace("EditForm.aspx", "docEditForm.aspx");

  lstTest.DefaultEditFormUrl = newUrl;

  lstTest.Update();

}
```

[For more information see this link](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/05/12/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-how-to-create-a-customized-list-edit-form-for-development-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)